# React function component prop default with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm having trouble with a React function component and defaulting a required prop.

Here's the component:

```
type Props = { message: string };
function Greeting({ message = "How are you?" }: Props) {
  return <p>{message}</p>;
}
```

I should be able to consume it without passing the `message` prop:

```
<Greeting />
```

However, TypeScript raises a type error *Property 'message' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Props'*:

[image]

Here's the issue in a CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/still-microservice-lp7b5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

I wasn't sure whether I am doing something wrong or whether this is a glitch in TypeScript? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This needs to be used as an example question somewhere. Very well asked.

Comment: `Property 'message' is missing in type '{}' but required in type 'Props'.ts `

It says you have required props type. Which is why typescript screams for this :) 
Just change type props like this  `message?:string`.

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to add the JavaScript tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Props` type definition has a **required** argument of `message`, however **you're treating it as an optional argument**. This is also referenced in the error message you're getting

- > *Property '`message`' is missing in type '`{}`' but required in type '`Props`'*
- Understand the error message as - your `type Props` has a required property of `message` however, your provided type `{}`, which is missing it *(read `{}` as no provided properties)*

---

Change the definition to the following way:

```
type Props = {
   message?: string; //< note the '?' at the end of property
};
```

Now if the component is returned without a specific `message`  prop, it will default to `"How are you?"`